# I cannot make Contact Form work as it returns an error

Tags: javascript, html, function, contact-form

I am developing a Contact Form for a web page for users to contact the company, the problem is the once I submit the information of the required fieldsets it returns an error alert that only needs to display if these fieldsets (an input and a textarea) are left empty.

Here is the HTML:

```html
                        <form>
                            <fieldset class="form-group" id="form-group">

                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset class="form-group" id="form-group2">

                                <textarea type="message" class="form-control" id="exampleMessage" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            </fieldset>

                            <!--Avoid redirect to another page (or will not reload).-->
                            <form onsubmit="return false">
                            </form>

                            <br>

                            <form action="?" method="POST">
                              <div class="g-recaptcha" class="recaptcha_footer" style="padding-left: 20px !important;" data-sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI" data-secretkey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe" data-callback="recaptcha_callback" data-theme="dark"></div>
                              <br/>
                              <!--input type="submit" value="Submit"-->
                            </form>
                            
                            <br>

                            <fieldset class="form-group text-xs-right">
                              <button onclick="sendContact();" type="submit" id="submit" disabled>Send</button>
                            </fieldset>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```js
          <script>
            function getDataInput() {
            return document.querySelector('input[id="exampleInputEmail1"]:checked', 'textarea[id="exampleMessage"]:checked')
            }
            //Group fields into an object
            var fieldset = {};

            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
             fieldset.exampleInputEmail1 = document.getElementById('#exampleInputEmail1');
             fieldset.exampleMessage = document.getElementById('#exampleMessage');
            })

            //Checking that the field is not empty 
            function isNotEmpty(value) {
            if (value == null || typeof value == 'undefined' ) return false;
            return (value.length > 0);
            }

            //Check if a string is an email
            function isEmail(email) {
            let regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
            return regex.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
            }

            //Prepare all validation functions
            function fieldValidation(fieldset, validationFunction) {
            if (fieldset == null) return false;

            let isFieldValid = validationFunction(fieldset.value)
            if (!isFieldValid) {
            fieldset.className = 'placeholderRed';
            } else {
            fieldset.className = '';
            }

            return isFieldValid;
            }

            //isValid: central function for checking the validity of our contact form
            function isValid() {
            var valid = true;
 
            valid &= fieldValidation(fieldset.exampleInputEmail1, isNotEmpty);
            valid &= fieldValidation(fieldset.exampleMessage, isNotEmpty);

            return valid;
          }

          //User class constructor: Combine multiple values under the same roof
          class User {
          constructor(exampleInputEmail1, exampleMessage) {
          this.exampleInputEmail1 = exampleInputEmail1;
          this.exampleMessage = exampleMessage;
           }
          }

          //Sending the contact form data
          function sendContact() {
            fieldset.exampleInputEmail1, fieldset.exampleMessage = getDataInput();

            if (isValid()) {
              let usr = new User(exampleInputEmail1.value, exampleMessage.value);

              alert('Thanks for submiting, we will be in touch shortly.')

            } else {
              alert("There was an error")
            }
          }

          </script>
```

Comment: For starters having a `#` in `document.getElementById` is invalid. just use the ID as is. Essentially your fieldset is 2 keys with values of null

Comment: What is this line doing? `fieldset.exampleInputEmail1, fieldset.exampleMessage = getDataInput()` it's destroying your `textarea` reference.

Comment: Thanks, it actually works. Now, how do I receive the submitted data? I mean do I need to insert my email to receive it there or where can I check it?